# Running liquibase script in google cloud platform

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, liquibase

I am trying to run liquibase to create DB schema and tables in GCP.
Below error is coming any idea ?

```
Class [org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.hbm.spi.package-info] could not be found. 
Processing bindings will probably fail.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.hbm.spi.package-info
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:315)
```

Comment: Any answer on this one would be highly appreciated ?

Comment: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3446

Comment: For a quick test you could try a version of liquibase < 3.7.0. (check out the link for details)

Answer (score 3):

I had to downgrade my Liquibase version to 3.6.3 (as suggested by @Jens). Now I am not getting the error.

Stack I use: Ubuntu 18.04 / OpenJDK 11

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue but it was only warning and it was not a stopper for us. To remove the warning, we upgraded the Liquibase version into version - 4.7.1 and the warning is gone.